# is there an R function for merging duplicates to the same row?

Tags: r

I am conducting research on SARS-CoV-2 test on healthcare workers. Some workers were tested multiple times (they are identified by employee number). Therefore I would like to have a new column were the second/third test-value (=numeric) and date of test is listed for the same healthcare worker. However, I am completely oblivious as to how to approach this. I'd guess you could group by duplicate for the employee number and use some sort of mutate() function?

All tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could utilize the `dcast` function from `library(data.table)`:
Lets asume you have the following data table:

`cov_test <- data.table(worker_id =c(1,1,2),test_count=c(1,2,1),test_result=c("negative", "positive","negative"))`

| worker_id | test_count | test_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test 1 | negative |
| 1 | test 2 | positive |
| 2 | test 1 | negative |

Using the following code you get following table:
`dcast(data = cov_test, ...~test_count, value.var="test_result")`

| worker_id | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | negative | positive |
| 2 | negative | NA |

The question is whether you have a column that describes the current test number for a person. If not, you would have to extract this information from the date column.

Comment: This looks useful, I do not however have the test number. I only have raw data from all tests and the only way of distinguishing the second/third test is that they have the same worker_id :)